# Why this manifold can not be embbeded in 3d Euclidean space?

Tags: manifolds

Consider the following system of 6 equations in 9 variables $x_1, x_2,x_3,...x_9$

$
x_1 ^ 2 + x_2 ^ 2 + x_3 ^ 2 + = 1
$

$
x_4 ^ 2 + x_5 ^ 2 + x_6 ^ 2 + = 1
$

$
x_7 ^ 2 + x_8 ^ 2 + x_9 ^ 2 + = 1
$

$
x_1 x_4 + x_2 x_6 + x_3 x_7 = 0
$

$
x_1 x_7 + x_2 x_8 + x_3 x_9 = 0
$

$
x_4 x_7 + x_5 x_8 + x_6 x_9 = 0
$

The solution space of this system is given as an example of a three dimensional compact manifold which can not be fully embedded in 3D but at any point, for instance $\left(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,\right)$, one can find a neighborhood of it which is in one to one correspondence with some neighborhood of Euclidean space.

Thank you

Comment: No compact n-manifold without boundary can be embedded in $\Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score 1):

> No compact $n$-manifold without boundary can be embedded in $\Bbb R^n$. -- [Mike Miller](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1406298/why-this-manifold-can-not-be-embbeded-in-3d-euclidean-space#comment2864631_1406298)

Indeed, since any $n$-manifold without boundary is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, the [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) implies that its image under an embedding  into $\mathbb{R}^n$ must be an open set. In particular, it cannot be compact.